# How to remove wordpress admin bar in dashboard

Tags: admin-bar, core, core-modifications

I would like to rebrand wordpress. Can anyone tell me how to remove it from dashboard?
Is there any hook available. Or I should edit core files. If i should edit core file can anyone tell me which file?

I edited `wp-includes/admin-bar.php` and removed this action

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 1000 );
```

It actually removed the admin bar. But it doesn't remove admin bar style sheet. I see empty space instead of admin bar. I mean i see padding in the top. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***NEVER*** edit core files.

Use the following code to disable admin bar.

```
add_action( 'init', 'disable_admin_bar', 1 );
function disable_admin_bar() {
    add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
}
```

NOTE: From WordPress 3.3 you can't remove admin bar in WordPress admin.

Comment: Yes i'm already using that kind of code for my front end. But i need to remove it in the wordpress admin. Thats why i'm editing core files. I know its bad habit editing core files and i can't update the wordpress if i edit core files. But i have no other choice

Comment: But the admin bar in WP3.3 is part of the admin interface, you said you are removing it for the purpose of rebranding, so rebrand the admin bar too.