# Disabling the Admin Bar | Where does code go?

Tags: admin-bar

I need to disable the admin bar for subscribing user ( not the admin).

I found these code snippets here on SE.

- [Best Option](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30309/how-do-i-remove-the-admin-bar-styling-from-frontend-only?rq=1)
- [Another Option](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37592/how-to-remove-wordpress-admin-bar-in-dashboard)

However I don't know what file to edit or where to put the code exactly.  I have experience with PHP, HTML, etc.  Just not so much with the WP (3.4.2).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would go in your theme's `functions.php` file. This is a small tweak, but things to remember are that:

- If you ever change your theme, you'll need to remember to copy this over to the new theme
- It'd be better to put these types of "system tweaks" into your own plugin, which you can read about [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)

Go with [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/37598/9605)

Comment: Please re-read my answer - `This would go in your theme's functions.php file`. So - something like `/wp-content/themes/YOURTHEME/functions.php` at the end, before the closing `?>`

Comment: Do you have a starter plugin I can use...to use as a repo for these little snippets...online maybe.

Comment: Sure - http://pastebin.com/hu2hPhDa just save that as something like `starter-plugin.php`, drop that in the `wp-content/plugins` directory and then activate it. You'll probably want to modify that header information to something else, but should be fine as-is. Thanks.

Comment: All you need is a comment..? Nice... WP makes life easy for starters!  Thanks!

Comment: Yes'm :) No problem!